# Combine two custom views

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am quite new to WPF and MVVM and I'm trying to figure this out...

#### What I want to achieve

- Having one view to search for customers (*CustomerSearchView*).
- Having several other views that can take advantage of the *CustomerSearchView* separately

#### Current situation

I implemented the beforementioned *CustomerSearchView* and a *CustomerSearchViewModel* behind it. The ViewModel has a property for the currently selected Item.

I implemented another view that enables the user to view and edit a customer (*CustomerEditView*). This view, of course, has a ViewModel of its own - the *CustomerEditViewModel*.

Now I want to have the user select a customer in the search view, that customer should then be visible (and ready to edit) in the detail view. **Note:** It is probable, that in the future I will have multiple windows or pages in the application that use a seperate *CustomerSearchView*. So sending a general event to a central event handler seems like the wrong approach to me.

What is the correct way to achieve this while sticking to MVVM?

Comment: `CustomerEditViewModel` needs that selected customer somehow: constructor parameter, property, method call, event handler for `CustomerSearchViewModel.SelectedCustomerChanged` or (what @Killazur suggested, not sure why he got downvote) better `ParentViewModel.SelectedCustomerChanged`...

Comment: `CustomerSearchView and a CustomerSearchViewModel` that's a code smell right there.  You gotta be careful with this, because it can go off the rails easily.  Think about this--does a TextBox have a TextBoxViewModel?  **No.**  It has a Text property that you bind to.  Be wary because you might end up having pseudo-DataContext properties so that you can essentially have two different DataContexts in order to actually use the control.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you must have some kind of general `CustomerViewModel`.

Let's say the parent viewmodel has a property:

```
public CustomerViewModel SelectedCustomer { /* INPC clutter */ }
```

Give the views each a dependency property of that type, and bind them.

```
<local:CustomerSearchView
    SelectedCustomer="{Binding SelectedCustomer}"
    />

<local:CustomerEditView
    EditedCustomer="{Binding SelectedCustomer}"
    />
```

`CustomerSearchView` will update its `SelectedCustomer` via a binding or something. We can go into that if it's not clear to you how to do it with what you've got.

`CustomerEditView` will have a property like this:

```
#region EditCustomer Property
public CustomerViewModel EditCustomer
{
    get { return (CustomerViewModel)GetValue(EditCustomerProperty); }
    set { SetValue(EditCustomerProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty EditCustomerProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(EditCustomer), typeof(CustomerViewModel), typeof(CustomerEditView),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, EditCustomer_PropertyChanged));

protected static void EditCustomer_PropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    (d as MainWindow).OnEditCustomerChanged(e.OldValue);
}

private void OnEditCustomerChanged(object oldValue)
{
    //  Or maybe your CustomerEditViewModel can acquire a new customer 
    //  to edit in some other way. 
    DataContext = new CustomerEditViewModel(EditCustomer);
}
#endregion EditCustomer Property
```

---

But that's not the way we do it in our application. For us, our parent viewmodel would have a `CustomerSearchViewModel CustomerSearch {...}` property and a `CustomerEditViewModel CustomerEdit {...}` property, plus the `SelectedCustomer` property as above. The parent viewmodel would be responsible for telling the `CustomerEditViewModel` what customer to edit when `SelectedCustomer` changes.

Then we'd have some implicit datatemplates in a resource dictionary that's merged into the main view:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{vm:CustomerSearchViewModel}">
    <vw:CustomerSearchView />
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{vm:CustomerEditViewModel}">
    <vw:CustomerEditView />
</DataTemplate>
```

Then in the parent view where the search and edit views are contained:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding CustomerSearch}" />
<ContentControl Content="{Binding CustomerEdit}" />
```

With this "viewmodel-first" approach, the views never provide their own viewmodels. On the other hand, this gets the parent viewmodel a little bit involved in UI design issues, like where the customer editor goes.

Comment: Or, you could have a public property `object CurrentOperation { /* INPC */}` in which you throw in the VM representing what you want to do--search, or edit.  Bind that to a Content control and with your data templates you're already at the bar having a drink.

Comment: @Will Throw in breadcrumb stack and a Back button, and make mine a double.

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple ways to do it, but the one I'd use is to have a parent ViewModel that'd hold references to your two ViewModels.

This parent would then have the responsibility of notifying each child of the changes of the other.

Another way would be to use a service class, that would hold data and provide some events for when this data is modified (these events would be called in your service properties' setters).
Your two ViewModels would subscribe to the events (thus properties) they're interested in, and react accordingly.

For the future of your application, if you don't want a central ViewModel to deal with everything, I would go with the services way.

*edit: If the downvote is because I'm not showing code, I haven't been shown any either, so I can't do much more than that.*